# Do the Borg have a language?

Tags: star-trek, borg, languages

I just realised something, with the amalgamation of species and cultures into the Borg, what language do they speak? I see three options but I can't find evidence for any:

1. The Language of Species 0001
2. The most efficient language they've found so far
3. Whichever language they need to use at the time

And we hear English via the [UT](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Universal_translator).

I can't see number one being popular, nor can I see 2 being helpful when they have to update documentation...

I'm stumped. Is there another, better, more correct answer? Which one is it? Can we know?

#### edit

I'm mostly interested in the times they speak to other species, however infrequently that is.

Comment: What language does the left hemisphere of your brain use to communicate with the right? Hmm... come to think of it, that's kind of an interesting question...

Comment: I keep thinking of the...Binars? I think, from the TNG episode where they steal the Enterprise, while giving Riker a good time in the holodeck. I always thought it would make a good episode to bring them together with the Borg in some way.

Comment: The binary language of moisture vaporators.

Comment: @Beta I believe It's called borgish. ;)

Comment: It's MSIL. Here's the proof: http://www.csis.ysu.edu/~kriss/funstuff/borg.MS.html

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As far as I understand the Borg, they don't use any language to communicate. They are a collective mind and are aware of each other's thoughts, presumably without the requirement for a language. However, at this point everything gets a bit esoteric; Can we think without language? If not, how are thoughts carried inside the brain?

Anyway, when communicating with non-Borg, spoken communication falls under the general "how do different species talk to each other" wibbly-wobbly. If the Borg Queen talks to Picard and Data in *First Contact* or to Janeway in *Endgame* they are either speaking English or one of the languages you list. With each other, they don't require a spoken language.

This is evidenced by the Borg Queen in *First Contact* referring to language as [primitive communication](http://www.chakoteya.net/movies/movie8.html):

> **BORG QUEEN**: Why do you insist on utilising this primitive linguistic
>   communication? Your android brain is capable of so much more.

Comment: I have just watched a VOY episode yesterday (I don't know which one, because I use it as a background noise while I'm doing my hobby) in which Harry Kim says something like "I don't know captain I can't speak borg(ish)." and later in that episode (or the following one) he says "I'm just trying to learn borg(ish).", (I'm not sure about the wording because I have seen it dubbed on my native language.) so I'm pretty sure there is a Borg language. I will try to clarify this when I get home from work, but I won't rewatch teh entire season for this.

Comment: In addition: Interestingly in the hungarian version of the Wikipedia article on the borg, there is an info box (in the English one there only is a logo). In this info box it says "language: borg tongue/neurocybernetic telepathy".

Comment: If I remember correctly it was the episode where he was to work with Seven. I suspect it was just a joke or meant as "I'm learning to to communicate in a manner that agrees with a [former] borg." Not specifically a literal language.

Comment: After two years, I can't say I'm sure, but I think it was presented like Harry actually spoke about a literal language course. But it could either be my mind playing tricks on me, or a glitch im dubbing.

Answer (score 11):

The use what, to me, sounds like a [form of very complex computer code as their language](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Borg_language).  Due to the link to the collective, all drones know it upon assimilation:

> the Borg used alphanumeric code as their written language and for
>   encoding and transmitting data throughout the Collective. Their
>   language consisted of circular symbols with geometric shapes cut out
>   of them. These symbols could be seen on various control panels,
>   labels, and viewscreens within Borg structures. It was written in many
>   different directions: in horizontal lines going from left to right and
>   right to left, and vertically. As the name suggests, the symbols
>   represented both alphabetic characters that represented sounds, and
>   numbers, with much Borg terminology comprising alphanumeric sequences.
>
> The code was immensely complex and consisted of at least fifty
>   characters and was stored, among other places, in data nodes. Despite
>   its complexity, other species could learn it. (VOY: "Revulsion")

And from about 11 and a half minutes into VOY 4x01, [Scorpion Part II](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Scorpion,_Part_II_%28episode%29), this screenshot - look at the blue circles for an example of Borg written language (they change as the scene goes on):

[image: Borg computer terminal]

Comment: [Their language consisted of circular symbols with geometric shapes cut out of them.](http://www.fontriver.com/i/specimens/ws_simple_gallifreyan_specimens.png)?

Comment: @Pureferret Some people also seem think the Guardian of Forever is the remnants of the Time Vortex... ;)